# Boolean expressions with unused variables?

Tags: boolean-logic

I'm auditing a knowledge base, and have noticed some Boolean expressions like:

A and (A or B)

This Boolean expression is notable because, of course, the value of B is actually irrelevant.  This may point to an error in the knowledge base, since the creator of the expression presumably intended for it to consider all variables it contains.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a name for this phenomenon?
2. Are there any efficient algorithms for identifying these unused/redundant variables?  I can do it using truth tables, but this breaks down for long expressions.  I've also looked at minimization algorithms, but many of them don't guarantee to find an optimal solution, so I'm not sure they're guaranteed to identify any unused variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are looking at an **Absorption**

   2. Those are known as **logical equivalences** and lists of well known and prooved equivalences exist. Algorithms may be similar to those used by programming language's interpreters or compilers and they are usually based on trees. You can use a tree to determine the type of expression that you are looking to and then match it to its corresponding logical equivalence. It's important that you also read about the precedence of your operators.

**Links**

- [Logical equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence#Logical_equivalences)
- [Order of precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence)
- [Syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)
- [Parse trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree)